# Is there any homomorphism of the additive group of the reals whose kernel is the subgroup of integers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Can we find a homomorphism $ \phi \colon (\mathbf{R}, +) \to (\mathbf{R}, +)$ whose kernel is the subgroup $(Z,+)$? Here $\mathbf{R}$ denotes the set of all real numbers, whereas $Z$ denotes the set of integers.

I'm trying the map $\phi \colon \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ defined by $\phi(x) \colon = x - \lfloor x \rfloor $ for all $x$ in $\mathbf{R}$, where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer not exceeding $x$, but I'm not managing to verify the homomorphism property $\phi(x+y) = \phi(x) + \phi(y)$ for all $x$, $y$ in $\mathbf{R}$.

I wonder if this is the correct map (if one exists)!

Comment: $\phi(1/2)+\phi(1/2)=0 \Longrightarrow 1/2 \in \ker \phi$.

Comment: If you did have a homomorphism, what kind of subgroup would be its kernel?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What are finite order elements of $R/Z$? What are finite order elements of $R$?

Comment: The finite order elements of $\mathbf{R}/Z$ are precisely those in the set $\{ q + Z \colon q \in \mathbf{Q} \}$, where $\mathbf{Q}$ is the set of rationals. On the other hand, only the element $0$ is of a finite order in $\mathbf{R}$. What next?

Comment: Next: Does homomorphism send finite order elements to finite order elements?